# Format a string "080616 1012" in date/time record type

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am trying to convert a string from this format "080616 1012" in date/time type.

I tried this

```
SELECT cdate(format("080616 1012", "##/##/#### ##:##"))   
FROM myData
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) how to format dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the date and time pieces separately.  Here is an example from the Access Immediate window:

```vb
strInput = "080616 1012"
? Format(Left(strInput, 6), "##\/##\/##")
8/06/16
? Format(Right(strInput, 4), "##\:##")
10:12
```

Then you can convert those formatted strings to Date/Time values:

```vb
? DateValue(Format(Left(strInput, 6), "##\/##\/##"))
8/6/2016 
? TimeValue(Format(Right(strInput, 4), "##\:##"))
10:12:00 AM
```

And finally add the two together:

```vb
? DateValue(Format(Left(strInput, 6), "##\/##\/##")) + TimeValue(Format(Right(strInput, 4), "##\:##"))
8/6/2016 10:12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a really simple method to chop strings for this purpose:

```
DateString = "080616 1012"
YourDate = CDate(Format(s, "@@/@@/@@@@@:@@"))

' Returns the date/time: 2016-06-08 10:12:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would literally break it apart, like so:
left(cdate,2)+'/'+substring(cdate,3,2)+'/20'+ substring(cdate,5,2), etc.